# Laravel session not work in AWS server

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I have configured Laravel website in AWS server but it is not working properly due to session execution.

I have configured PHP 7.0 and Laravel 5.4 in Apache 2.

Comment: Make sure you've set the correct folder permissions. From the doc "After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the `storage` and the `bootstrap/cache` directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run".

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information in this question to make it reasonably answerable. Have you checked your PHP logs?

Comment: @Sandeesh  , I have setup SSL url and it is not working SSL HTTPS url.

Comment: @halfer I have used HTTPS and i think it is not working session thing in HTTPS. Can you pls advice for it?

Comment: In that case, try HTTP to see if sessions work there. Also, use a cookie viewer in your browser to see if they are being persisted from request to request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this problem using below steps:

```
if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
    URL::forceSchema('https');
}
```

And It is working fine!!!!.